# Splitting String and put it on int array (no repeated ints) Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, int

So I have an input where the user create as much user-ids (int) as he feels like separated by commas ex: 1,3,12,5...
But I have to break apart the String that the user input and put it in an int array.
Also, there can't be any repeated user-ids. Why is this code wrong?

```
   private static Editor inicio(Scanner in){

    int[] users=null;

    System.out.println("What are the users you wish to create? (Separate by commas)");
    String option = in.nextLine();
    if (option.contains(",")){
        do{
            String[] vetorString = option.split(",");
            for(int i = 0; i < vetorString.length; i++) {
                users[i] = Integer.parseInt(vetorString[i]);
            }
        } while(hasUtilizador(users));
    }

    private static boolean hasUtilizador(int[] users){

       boolean duplicate=false;
       for (int j=0 ; j < users.length ; j++)
          for (int k=j+1 ; k < users.length ; k++)
             if (k!=j && users[k] == users[j])
                 duplicate=true;
          return duplicate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong because

```
users[i] = Integer.parseInt(vetorString[i]);
```

is called on a null array. Before you start assigning values to `users`, instantiate it with

```
users = new int[vectorString.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [String tokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and insert ',' as delimeters.